# 2 developers working on the same site, avoid overwriting each other

Tags: web-development, software

Recently my company took on another developer to work alongside me. We both use Coda 2 and there's times where we're both working on the same sites. It recently happened that we both wrote over each others changes.

Is there a way to avoid us overwriting each others changes within Coda? Or is there more software that we would need for some kind of version control.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about developing methodology 

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course. You may use [SVN](http://www.midwinter-dg.com/permalink-how_to_use_subversion_version_control_with_coda_on_the_mac_2010-11-18.html) (Subversion) or [GIT](http://blog.towatchlist.com/2012/05/developing-using-coda-2-with-git-part-1-configuring-your-git-repo-server/), which are both integrated into the Coda app. Since Mountain Lion, you have to do a bit more to use SVN by the way (see [Coda FAQ](https://panic.com/coda/support.html)).

Comment: Mich mostly nailed it. If you are on OSX = Versions is a wonderful cut-code management tool